# (or SLV is undefined) Informix data base

Tags: sql, database, informix

Can anyone help me out here to find out the error in this small query.

```
select count(txno) as c1, rxno  from mrgrxtxt 
where c1>1
group by rxno;
```

error:  `[Error Code: -217, SQL State: IX000]  Column (c1) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).`

If I comment out the WHERE clause (`where c1 >1`), it executes fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or do the `GROUP BY` part in a derived table:

```
select c1, rxno
from
(
    select count(txno) as c1, rxno 
    from mrgrxtxt 
    group by rxno
)
where c1 > 1;
```

Very convenient when more complex aggregations. (Less typing, and smaller risk of errors when duplicating or adjusting expressions.)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use column aliases in a `where`.  Really, you need a `having` clause.

Try this:

```
select count(txno) as c1, rxno 
from mrgrxtxt 
group by rxno
having count(txno) > 1;
```